# Stats for suggested edit reviews in review beta seem way off

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, statistics

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

[image: screenshot of statistics page]

The Review Beta suggested edits stats page currently says:

- 0 need review
- 2,395 reviews today
- 27,362 reviews all-time

I agree with the first one. I can get along with the second one, I guess, but I can't reconcile with the third one. Have almost 10% of all suggested edits ever been reviewed today?

My personal stats are wrong as well. It shows:

Today: 7
All-time: 22

If I go to [my review activity tab in my SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9453/daniel-dipaolo?tab=activity&sort=reviews), I see well over 400 suggested edits reviewed (as you can see on one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/323933)). Again, the statistics for today are right (I think), but the all-time stuff is a way off. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stats are only accurate since the panel has actually existed, which isn't very long. They don't retroactively include *all* suggested edits that have ever been made on the site. I'm not sure if they're planning on updating that or not (doubt it*). The review beta panel is still being worked on and is nowhere near completion yet.

* The previous review panel kept track of stats by only counting things you actually did *through* the review panel. Completing those actions on the post themselves outside the panel did not count, so it would only make sense that previous suggested edit reviews wouldn't contribute to the new task stats.

Comment: Seems fairly reasonable.  I wonder if it would make sense to clarify that or not, though.  I guess the ideal situation would be to sync it all up, if it's possible.

Comment: I don't believe they ever kept track of which suggested edits you approved via the queue before this point. There would be no way to tell whether it was reviewed via the queue or just in the body of the post.

Comment: I can confirm that even now, if you review a suggested edit through the old `/review` interface (which I still use, and I'd strongly prefer to the new one if Matt's script still worked), it isn't counted in the Review Beta stats (which are just that: the Review Beta stats).

Comment: @Gilles thanks, I think that basically settles it then :)

Answer (score 0):

Several weeks after launching the review beta system, we performed a backfill to add all of the *old* suggested edit reviews to the new system. Bear in mind that suggested edits were the only review type to be backfilled this way. You should see all of your historic suggested edit reviews in the new stats page now.